# How do I trigger two javaScript animations at once?

Tags: javascript, css, animation

I am currently facing a problem trying to make two animations work at the same time:

1. The first animation is to reveal hidden objects by changing the display property, and adding stylings to increase the height of a section
2. On click, a project should scroll into view in the center

Independently, these animations work fine, however I cannot get them to work together at the same time.

I have made a CodePen to help visualise the problem and also attach the code:
[Codepen](https://codepen.io/majiinbju/full/zYebLyy)

HTML

```html
<main>
  <!--   Start of projects   -->
  <div class="wrapper">
    <!--   Project 1   -->
    <section>
      <div class="carousel">
        <ul class="ul draggable">
          <li class="container project-info"></li>
          <li class="container one hidden"></li>
          <li class="container two hidden"></li>
          <li class="container three hidden"></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </section>
    <!--   Project 2   -->
    <section>
      <div class="carousel">
        <ul class="ul draggable">
          <li class="container project-info"></li>
          <li class="container one hidden"></li>
          <li class="container two hidden"></li>
          <li class="container three hidden"></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </section>
    <!--   End of projects   -->
  </div>
</main>
```

CSS

```css
:root {
  --transition: all 0.75s ease-in-out;
}
body {
  min-height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

/* Project list */
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0rem;
  min-height: 100vh;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
/* Default stylings for list */
.ul {
  display: flex;
  align-items: start;
  list-style-type: none;
}

/* Section for each project */
section {
  height: 30vh;
  width: 80%;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  transition: var(--transition);
  transform-origin: center; /* Set the transform origin to the center */
}
/* Active state for section */
section.active {
  transform: translateX(0);
  transform-origin: center; /* Set the transform origin to the center */
}

/* Block styles */
.container {
  margin: 0 1rem;
  width: 600px;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
  background: red;
}
.one {
  background: blue;
}
.two {
  background: green;
}
.three {
  background: yellow;
}

/* JavaScript Classes */
/* Hidden elements */
.hidden {
  opacity: 0;
  display: none;
  transition: var(--transition); /* Transition opacity */
}
/* Show object */
.showObject {
  opacity: 1;
  animation: fadeIn 0.75s ease-in-out;
  display: flex;
  transition: var(--transition); /* Transition opacity */
}
```

JavaScript

```javascript
gsap.registerPlugin(Draggable);
const bodyElement = document.querySelector(".wrapper");
const mainElement = document.querySelector("main");
const sections = document.querySelectorAll("section");

let isDragging = false;
let lastTouch = 0;
let isScrolling = false;
let scrollSpeed = 0;
let lastScrollTime = 0;
let lastScrollDelta = 0;
let sx = 0,
  sy = 0;
let dx = sx,
  dy = sy;
let scrollTimeout;
let expandTimeout;

sections.forEach((section) => {
  const carousel = section.querySelector(".carousel");
  let isDragging = false;
  let startX = 0;
  let endX = 0;

  // Loop through each element and make it draggable using GSAP Draggable
  document.querySelectorAll(".draggable").forEach((element) => {
    gsap.set(element, { x: 0 }); // Set initial x position

    Draggable.create(element, {
      type: "x", // Restrict movement to horizontal axis
      bounds: element.parentElement, // Restrict movement within the parent element
      edgeResistance: 1, // Simulate 'endOnly' behavior from interact.js
      onDrag: function () {
        // Update the element's transform during drag
        gsap.set(element, { x: this.x });
      },
      onRelease: function () {
        // This is similar to the 'end' listener in interact.js
        // You can add any necessary logic here when dragging ends
      }
    });
  });
  carousel.addEventListener("mousedown", (e) => {
    isDragging = true;
    startX = e.clientX || e.touches[0].clientX;
  });

  carousel.addEventListener("mouseup", (e) => {
    if (isDragging) {
      isDragging = false;
      endX = e.clientX || e.changedTouches[0].clientX;

      const distance = endX - startX;
      const momentum = 0.9; // Adjust momentum factor as needed
      const duration = 750; // Adjust duration for animation

      const distanceWithMomentum = distance * momentum;
      const targetX = carousel.scrollLeft + distanceWithMomentum;

      gsap.to(carousel, {
        scrollLeft: targetX,
        duration: duration,
        ease: "power2.out"
      });
    }
  });

  carousel.addEventListener("mouseleave", () => {
    isDragging = false;
  });
  const hidden = section.querySelectorAll(".hidden");

  if (window.innerWidth > 768) {
    section.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
      if (!isDragging && !section.classList.contains("active")) {
        sections.forEach((s) => {
          if (s !== section && s.classList.contains("active")) {
            s.classList.remove("active");
            let projectInfo = s.querySelector(".project-info");
            projectInfo
              .querySelectorAll(".hidden.showObject")
              .forEach((obj) => {
                obj.classList.remove("showObject");
              });
            s.style.transition =
              "transform 0.75s ease-in-out, height 0.75s, width 0.75s ease-in-out";
            s.style.transform = "none";
            s.style.height = "30vh";
          }
        });

        section.classList.add("active");

        setTimeout(() => {
          hidden.forEach((hide) => {
            hide.classList.add("showObject");
          });

          const expandTransitionDuration = 750;
          setTimeout(() => {
            const sectionsBefore = Array.from(sections).slice(
              0,
              Array.from(sections).indexOf(section)
            );
            const totalHeightBefore = sectionsBefore.reduce(
              (total, sec) => total + sec.clientHeight,
              0
            );
            const headerHeight = 90;
            const targetScroll =
              totalHeightBefore +
              headerHeight -
              (window.innerHeight - section.clientHeight) / 2;

            window.scrollTo({
              top: targetScroll,
              behavior: "smooth"
            });
          }, expandTransitionDuration);

          bodyElement.classList.add("expand");
          clearTimeout(expandTimeout); // Clear previous timeout if exists
          expandTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
            bodyElement.classList.remove("expand");
          }, 0); // Delay class removal after scrolling stops
        }, 750);

        section.style.transition =
          "transform 0.75s ease-in-out, height 0.75s, width 0.75s ease-in-out";
        section.style.transformOrigin = "center center";
        section.style.height = "80vh";
        section.style.width = "100%";
      }
    });
  }

  section.addEventListener("touchstart", () => {
    isDragging = true;
  });

  section.addEventListener("touchend", () => {
    isDragging = false;
    lastTouch = new Date().getTime();
  });
});

window.addEventListener("wheel", (event) => {
  const currentTime = new Date().getTime();
  const isTrackpad = currentTime - lastTouch < 100; // Adjust the time threshold as needed

  if (!isDragging) {
    const delta = event.deltaY || event.detail || -event.wheelDelta;

    if (Math.abs(delta) > 1) {
      if (
        isTrackpad ||
        event.deltaX !== undefined ||
        event.deltaY !== undefined
      ) {
        bodyElement.classList.add("expand");

        setTimeout(() => {
          bodyElement.classList.remove("expand");
        }, 100); // Adjust the delay time as needed
      }
    }
  }
});

function easeScroll() {
  sx = window.pageXOffset;
  sy = window.pageYOffset;
}

window.requestAnimationFrame(render);

function render() {
  dx = li(dx, sx, 0.07);
  dy = li(dy, sy, 0.07);
  dx = Math.floor(dx * 100) / 100;
  dy = Math.floor(dy * 100) / 100;

  mainElement.style.transform = `translate3d(-${dx}px, -${dy}px, 0px)`;

  document.body.style.height = "0";
  window.requestAnimationFrame(render);
}

function li(a, b, n) {
  return (1 - n) * a + n * b;
}

function updateScroll() {
  if (scrollSpeed !== 0) {
    window.scrollBy(0, scrollSpeed);
    scrollSpeed *= 0.9;

    if (Math.abs(scrollSpeed) < 0.1) {
      scrollSpeed = 0;
    }
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(updateScroll);
}

updateScroll();
```

P.S. The JavaScript is so verbose as I am using KirbyCMS to build this website, and it doesn't support the use of modules (or at least I don't think so), and if anybody could guide me as to how I can truncate the code that would be great. Any help would be much appreciated, thank you in advance!

So far I have tried to:

- Tried changing the transition delay speed to match that of the animation (0.75s)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.